# Daily climatology for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
        id      vi       dates     f_id
0  5532714  0.549501  2015-07-07    ff_22
1  5532715  0.540969  2015-07-08    ff_22
2  5532716  0.531477  2015-07-09    ff_22
3  5532717  0.521029  2016-07-09    ff_22
4  5532718  0.509694  2017-07-11    ff_22
```

In the dataframe above, I want to compute climatology i.e. daily average for a dataframe spanning multiple years. Currently I tried this:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)
df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day])['vi'].transform('mean')
```

I want the output to not have a multi-index.

Comment: Do you need aggreagte data or use transform? Check last paragraph of my answer for difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need assign to new column:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)
df['new'] = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day])['vi'].transform('mean')
print (df)
                 id        vi       dates   f_id       new
dates                                                     
2015-07-07  5532714  0.549501  2015-07-07  ff_22  0.549501
2015-07-08  5532715  0.540969  2015-07-08  ff_22  0.540969
2015-07-09  5532716  0.531477  2015-07-09  ff_22  0.526253
2016-07-09  5532717  0.521029  2016-07-09  ff_22  0.526253
2017-07-11  5532718  0.509694  2017-07-11  ff_22  0.509694
```

---

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)
df = df.assign(new=df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day])['vi'].transform('mean'))
print (df)
                 id        vi       dates   f_id       new
dates                                                     
2015-07-07  5532714  0.549501  2015-07-07  ff_22  0.549501
2015-07-08  5532715  0.540969  2015-07-08  ff_22  0.540969
2015-07-09  5532716  0.531477  2015-07-09  ff_22  0.526253
2016-07-09  5532717  0.521029  2016-07-09  ff_22  0.526253
2017-07-11  5532718  0.509694  2017-07-11  ff_22  0.509694
```

And then if necessary `reset_index`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
        id        vi       dates   f_id       new
0  5532714  0.549501  2015-07-07  ff_22  0.549501
1  5532715  0.540969  2015-07-08  ff_22  0.540969
2  5532716  0.531477  2015-07-09  ff_22  0.526253
3  5532717  0.521029  2016-07-09  ff_22  0.526253
4  5532718  0.509694  2017-07-11  ff_22  0.509694
```

But it seems better is convert column `date` to `datetime`, then `reset_index` is not necessary:

```
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)
df['new'] = df.groupby([df.dates.dt.month, df.dates.dt.day])['vi'].transform('mean')
print (df)

        id        vi      dates   f_id       new
0  5532714  0.549501 2015-07-07  ff_22  0.549501
1  5532715  0.540969 2015-07-08  ff_22  0.540969
2  5532716  0.531477 2015-07-09  ff_22  0.526253
3  5532717  0.521029 2016-07-09  ff_22  0.526253
4  5532718  0.509694 2017-07-11  ff_22  0.509694
```

If for some reason cannot convert column to `datetime` is possible use:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)
df['new'] = df.groupby([d.dt.month, d.dt.day])['vi'].transform('mean')
print (df)
        id        vi       dates   f_id       new
0  5532714  0.549501  2015-07-07  ff_22  0.549501
1  5532715  0.540969  2015-07-08  ff_22  0.540969
2  5532716  0.531477  2015-07-09  ff_22  0.526253
3  5532717  0.521029  2016-07-09  ff_22  0.526253
4  5532718  0.509694  2017-07-11  ff_22  0.509694
```

### ---

Difference between `transform` and `aggregation`:

```
#changed sample data - dates    
print (df)
        id        vi       dates   f_id
0  5532714  0.549501  2015-07-07  ff_22
1  5532715  0.540969  2016-07-07  ff_22
2  5532716  0.531477  2015-07-09  ff_22
3  5532717  0.521029  2016-07-11  ff_22
4  5532718  0.509694  2017-07-11  ff_22
```

[`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) is used for new columns in original `DataFrame` - size of output `df` is not changed, so same data for same group:

```
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)
df['new'] = df.groupby([df.dates.dt.month, df.dates.dt.day])['vi'].transform('mean')
print (df)
        id        vi      dates   f_id       new
0  5532714  0.549501 2015-07-07  ff_22  0.545235
1  5532715  0.540969 2016-07-07  ff_22  0.545235
2  5532716  0.531477 2015-07-09  ff_22  0.531477
3  5532717  0.521029 2016-07-11  ff_22  0.515362
4  5532718  0.509694 2017-07-11  ff_22  0.515362
```

But if aggregate by [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) size of output `df` is changed, but another columns are not in output (if need them, is necessary aggregate each column by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)):

```
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)
df1 = df.groupby([df.dates.dt.month, df.dates.dt.day])['vi'].mean()
        .rename_axis(('months', 'days')).reset_index()
print (df1)
   months  days        vi
0       7     7  0.545235
1       7     9  0.531477
2       7    11  0.515362
```

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a categorical index to group by.  I chose to format the dates with `'%b, %d'` but you can use any month/day combination derived from the options at [strftime.org](http://strftime.org).

Consider the dataframe `df` consisting of 4 years of random daily data:

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2013-12-31', name='dates')

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(vi=np.random.rand(tidx.size)), tidx)
```

---

I'll choose to make my category labels from `2012` because it is a leap year and will include `Feb 29`.  By creating categories, pandas will know that `Jan, 01` comes before `Aug, 31`.

```
fmt = '%b, %d'
categories = pd.CategoricalIndex(
    df.index.strftime(fmt),
    pd.date_range('2012-01-01', '2012-12-31').strftime(fmt)
)
df.groupby(categories).mean()

               vi
Jan, 01  0.452812
Jan, 02  0.422205
Jan, 03  0.409369
Jan, 04  0.620173
Jan, 05  0.456044
Jan, 06  0.616172
Jan, 07  0.693760
Jan, 08  0.636427
Jan, 09  0.490981
Jan, 10  0.412720
Jan, 11  0.516009
Jan, 12  0.372129
...           ...
Dec, 20  0.523669
Dec, 21  0.372038
Dec, 22  0.609447
Dec, 23  0.568481
Dec, 24  0.612216
Dec, 25  0.765035
Dec, 26  0.368508
Dec, 27  0.558909
Dec, 28  0.371733
Dec, 29  0.516978
Dec, 30  0.654397
Dec, 31  0.793721

[366 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about `pd.CategoricalIndex` ! :)